# Problem in selecting rows from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select, nan

I encounter an error when I tried to extract rows from DataFrame where the rows match the conditions.
The code I used is a very simple one:

```
    for c in classes:
           print(X[y == c])
```

where *X* is features of samples in DataFrame, *y* is classes of the samples in DataFrame, and *c* is a list of class labels.
I used this code for two data sets, and it works with a dataset, but does not with the other, although the both are formatted in the same way.

With the data set I had an error, I printed `y == c` by:

```
     print(y == c)
```

and it returned this:

```
           Classes
     0     True
     1     True
     2     True
           ...
     4572  False
     4573  False
     4574  False
```

Therefore, I am assuming that the condition matching is working properly. 
However, when I print `X[y == c]` by:

```
  print(X[y == c])
```

the result is like this:

```
            0   1   2
     0    NaN NaN NaN
     1    NaN NaN NaN
     2    NaN NaN NaN
     3    NaN NaN NaN
           ...
     4574 NaN NaN NaN
```

To note, the *X* and *y* are ordinary DataFrame that looks like these:
**X**

```
                     0           1          2
     0       -3.786900    9.411757  -2.246594
     1      742.632101  -74.001353  -0.567936
     2     2019.854074  102.077111 -23.776775
     3      -93.048341    3.008569  -1.043599
           ...
     4754  -247.754953   -6.851270  -0.984777
```

**y**

```
            Classes
     0      0
     1      0
     2      0
            ...
     4572   2
     4573   2
     4574   2
```

Can this problem be sorted out?

Comment: There are same length of indices in both DataFrames? `print (len(X.index))` and `print (len(Y.index))` ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are same length of data and same index values in both `DataFrames` use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) by column `Classes` along `0` axis for boolean `DataFrame`, then check at least one `True` per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = X[X.eq(Y['Classes'], axis=0).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the problem.
`X` and `y` are the same length. I had the above problem only with Data1, but not with Data2.

I checked the data type of `y` in Data1 and Data2, and found that `y` was

- < class 'pandas.core.**series.Series**> with Data2 (working)
- < class 'pandas.core.**frame.DataFrame**'> with Data1 (not working)

I converted `y` in Data1 into Series by:

```
    y = y.ix[:,0]
```

,then extraction of rows came to work properly.